# Is it OK to have a throwing swap member-implementation?

Tags: c++, swap, exception-safe, copy-and-swap, exception-safety

The general guideline when writing classes (using the copy-and-swap idiom) is to provide a non throwing swap member function. ([Effective C++, 3rd edition, Item 25](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) and other resources)

However, what if I cannot provide the nothrow guarantee because my class uses a 3rd party class member that doesn't provide a swap operation?

```
// Warning: Toy code !!!

class NumberBuffer {
public:
    ...
    void swap(NumberBuffer& rhs);

public:
    float* m_data;
    size_t m_n;
    CString m_desc;
};

void swap(NumberBuffer& lhs, NumberBuffer& rhs) {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}

void NumberBuffer::swap(NumberBuffer& rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(m_data, rhs.m_data);
    swap(m_n, rhs.m_n);
    swap(m_desc, rhs.m_desc); // could throw if CString IsLocked and out-of-mem
}
```

CString swap cannot be made no-throw, so there's the off chance the swap could fail.

Note: For rare 3rd party classes, using a smart ptr (pimpl) would be an option, *but* --

Note: CString is a good example as noone in his right mind (?) would start holding all members of a conceptually simple and ubiquitous class like CString via pimpl (smart ptr) because that would really look horrible -- and on the other hand, there's no (short to mid-term) chance to get the CString modified to allow fully no-throw swap.

So, *is it OK to have a potentially throwing swap member function if you can't help it*? (Or do you know ways around this conundrum?)

Edit: And: Can a throwing swap member be used with the copy-and-swap idiom to provide the basic guarantee if not the strong guarantee?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you can move away from `CString` then the problem would be gone...

Comment: Be aware that on a similar subject, some fairly small number of years down the line you are going to have the same problem when you try to implement C++11 move for your class. If the member can't be nothrow-swapped, then chances are it isn't going to be nothrow-movable either, because the two are very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is it OK to have a potentially throwing swap member function if you can't help it? (Or do you know ways around this conundrum?)

There is nothing inherently *wrong* with having a `swap` function that can potentially throw, but beware that without the strong exception guarantee in `swap`, it cannot possibly be used to provide exception safety, that is, it can only be used as `swap` (that is, forget about the copy-and-swap idiom for that particular class as a way of providing the strong exception guarantee... but you can still use it to reduce the amount of code --and document that it is not exception safe)

Alternatively, you can move the `CString` into a smart pointer that offers a no-throw `swap` (or at the very least the strong exception guarantee), not a nice solution, but it will at least be exception safe. Lastly, you can move away from `CString` altogether by using any other string library that provides whatever you need and offers a no-throw swap operation.

Comment: +1 Can you draw a little connection from exception-safety to thread-safety? Or is this a typo?

Comment: @ChristianRau: likely typo given the context... in fact it is so obvious that I subconsciously read *exception* safety :)

Comment: @ChristianRau: it was a typo, sorry for that. I am a bit tired :)

Comment: David - yeah, no strong guarantee and as far as I can see, *also* no basic guarantee (?) unless you take a lot of care. What do you think? Could this swap be used in the copy-and-swap idiom at all? Or would one have to add some try-catch-revert stuff to provide the basic guarantee? (Maybe you could edit your answer to include this.)

Comment: @Martin: you are right in that this `swap` cannot be used to provide *any* exception guarantee. The basic guarantee could be implemented by wrapping inside a try/catch, but that is basically the same with any random piece of code...

Comment: I think you're wrong - the copy and swap idiom provides the strong exception guarantee if `swap` provides the strong exception guarantee or better.

Comment: @JoeGauterin: How does that contradict what I said? (oh, right, the `swap` does not need to be no-throw, only provide the strong exception guarantee)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez: Yes, you said that "without the no throw guarantee that swap cannot possibly be used to provide exception safety".

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with a throwing `swap`, it is just less useful than a no-throw version.

The copy and swap idiom doesn't need `swap` to be no-throw in order to provide the strong exception guarantee. `swap` needs only to provide the strong exception guarantee.

The difficulty is that if the no-throw guarantee cannot be provided, it is also likely that the strong exception guarantee cannot be provided. Naive swapping using a temporary and three copies only provides the basic guarantee unless the copying operation provides the no-throw guarantee, in which case swap is also no-throw.

Comment: Excellent points wrt. no-throw vs. strong. If there's only one member that doesn't provide the no-throw guarantee, then it's just a matter of swapping (copying) that first to get the strong-guarantee. If there's more than one member, I think one's out of luck.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily make it nothrow:

```
void NumberBuffer::swap(NumberBuffer& rhs) throw()
{
    try
    {
        std::swap(m_desc, rhs.m_desc);   //could throw
        std::swap(m_data, rhs.m_data);
        std::swap(m_n, rhs.m_n);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

Of course, this is no real solution to the problem, but now you at least got your non-throwing swap ;)

Comment: Except that that `swap` doesn't fulfill it's contract and *silently* fails! Happy time finding those errors! I suggest you either qualify your example as how to *not* do it or delete the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin It wasn't meant too serious and I realize a comment would have been better for this, but feel free to down-vote.

Comment: Given the `throw()` exception specification, this would be better without the try/catch. That way the compiler will arrange for `std::terminate` to be called if it throws, at least provided you're not in some non-compliant mode of MSVC. Still might not be what the caller wants, but at least it's obvious something is wrong.

Comment: "_It wasn't meant too serious_" It was pretty obvious IMO. Is there a "funny" button? (as in /.)